# Resolve SQL Injection Error from Checkmarx using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate reading parameterized query from a file

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, sql-injection, checkmarx

The query is read from a file in the resources folder of the java spring boot application.
How do I prevent this Sql Injection error from Checkmarx in the code below?

```
@Repository
public class ItemRepository {

  @Autowired
  NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  public List<Item> getData(String action) {
    String sql = IOUtils.toString(getClass().getResourceAsStream("queries/query.sql"));
    MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    parameters.addValue("action", action, Types.VARCHAR);

    try {
      List<Item> items = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, parameters, new ItemMapper());
      return items;
    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException ex) {
      return new ArrayList<>();
    }
  }
}
```

Error message:

> The application's `getData` method executes an SQL query with `query`, at line 13 of `ItemRepository.java`. The application constructs this SQL query by embedding an untrusted string into the query without proper sanitization. The concatenated string is submitted to the database, where it is parsed and executed accordingly.
> An attacker would be able to inject arbitrary syntax and data into the SQL query, by crafting a malicious payload and providing it via the input `toString`; this input is then read by the `getData` method at line 8 of `ItemRepository.java`. This input then flows through the code, into a query and to the database server - without sanitization.
> **This may enable an SQL Injection attack.**

Comment: which version of Checkmarx SAST are you using?

Comment: I see it is V 9.4.5 HF15

Answer (score 0):

Checkmarx is likely complaining about the SQL string coming via a stream.  In this specific case it's coming from a resource file in a jar, which is probably a trusted source in your application.  If so, this is a false positive and you should mark it Not Exploitable (with the appropriate reasoning).

Comment: yes, I reached out to the admin and had it marked as not exploitable.

Comment: You should only do it if you 100% trust what comes out of the file. A malicious payload from a file can still cause a stored SQL injection attack.

Comment: @yaloner I trust this file but say I don't, what's a more secure way to write this code?

Comment: @pradhyo - There's no way to sanitize or validate a full SQL statement (or even a fragment).  This should never be a value from an untrusted source.   The correct thing to do would be to split this into SQL from a trusted source, and parameters (from an untrusted source).  The params would be used in a parameterized query or positively validated.